# Permissions to add/edit all entries in a list, without giving 'Manage Lists' permission

Tags: 2010, list, calendar

Is it possible to set permissions for a SharePoint 2010 list (a Calendar in particular) to allow editing all entries (not just ones the user creates) without given them Full Access or Manage Lists?

**Update**
Some users will want access to only edit their own items, others edit any (but not manage the list)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom permission level. This will give you the possibility to grant only the permissions you want to. Here is an article about how to do it:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Disable the item level permissions in Advanced Permissions so users can edit all items and give them Contribute permission to the list.

Comment: I want some users to only edit their own entries and some to delete any (but not manage the list)

Comment: That wasn't mentioned anywhere in the description.